# keeping track of a moving shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I hope someone can help me out. For the past month or so I have be learning the Bash... I have a program ( a simple language study program ) that I want to be able to install and run from a script.

I have a script that will create a new folder and move itself into it. The way I am doing it at the moment is below, although I have had problems with arrays that I am using later. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of getting the new path to file name. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "# path to me --------------->  ${0}     "
echo "# parent path -------------->  ${0%/*}  "
echo "# my name ------------------>  ${0##*/} "

if [[ ! -d ${0%/*}/SomeNewFolder ]] && [[ ! -d ${0%/*}/../SomeNewFolder ]]
then
    mkdir ${0%/*}/SomeNewFolder
    mv ${0} ${0%/*}/SomeNewFolder/${0##*/}
fi

echo ${0%/*}
newpath=$(echo "${0%/*}/SomeNewFolder")
echo $newpath
```

All the best, Ben
    exit

Comment: By the way, the echo in backticks is an antipattern, unless you know exactly why you are doing it.  See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, I would probably declare named variables for your common values instead of constantly reusing the ${0} array. It's also good practice to quote variables and strings.

The only major issue I saw, was running ./script.sh would make $0 equal just the filename, so I add "./" to the beginning in that case.

```
#!/bin/bash -u

ME="${0}"
if [[ ! "$ME" =~ /^\// ]]; then
        ME="./$ME"
fi
PARENT="${ME%/*}"
FILENAME="${ME##*/}"
FOLDER="SomeNewFolder"
NEW="$PARENT/$FOLDER"

if [[ ! -d "$NEW" ]] && [[ "${PARENT%/*}" != "$FOLDER" ]]; then
        mkdir "$NEW"
        mv "$ME" "$NEW"
fi

echo "$PARENT"
echo "$NEW"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like this to get an absolute path:

```
PARENTPATH=$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )
NEWPATH=${PARENTPATH}/SomeNewFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing and setting up programs is more appropriately done from a make file. Granted, it seems intimidating at first, but the basics, such as what you want, are quite simple. For your project, you would ideally have three item:

1. your program
2. your run script
3. your makefile i.e. your installer

This breaks apart each of these different components, making each of them easier to manage. If you tar them together, you can move the tar file to a new computer and reinstall without any changes. Bash is a wonderful tool, but an installer it is not.

Sample make script below:

```
.PHONY: all clean
SCRIPT=yourScriptName.sh
SUBFOLDER=someFolder

all: $(SCRIPT)

$(SCRIPT): $(SUBFOLDER)
    cp $(SCRIPT) $(SUBFOLDER)    
$(SUBFOLDER): 
    mkdir $(SUBFOLDER)
clean:
    -rm -f $(SUBFOLDER)/$(SCRIPT)
    -rmdir $(SUBFOLDER)
```

**IMPORTANT!** make is whitespace sensitive! Those indents are *tabs* not four spaces.

Comment: Perhaps 'Program' was a strong word. It is more like a 400 line bash script that can accept user input etc... the install part is really just to let people set it up the fist time they run the script. I am trying to understand if $0 can ever be updated... could I use a make file for bash scripts? 'installer' and 'program'? I'll have a read through the man make page...

Comment: @user969617 Make can work for anything, and a shell script is still a program. :) Most the time, personal shell scripts go into a users ~/bin folder, but if you intend to push it out to people, then a simple "installer" is good form.

Answer (score 0):

```
me="$0"
newdir=SomeNewFolder

if [[ $me =~ ^/ ]] ; then
    full_path="$me"
else
    full_path="$PWD/$me"
fi
full_path="${full_path//\/\.\///}" # prettify

path_to_me="${full_path%/*}"
parent_dir="${path_to_me##*/}"

if [ ! "$parent_dir" = "$newdir" ] ; then
    mkdir -p "$path_to_me/$newdir"
    mv -f "$full_path" "$path_to_me/$newdir/"
fi
```

Basically similar to what lunixbochs was doing, but with a few minor alterations

1. lower case variable names so as not to be confused with environment variables
2. crudely estimates absolute path
3. `-f` and `-p` becuase interactivity is never cool, and why not

Comment: It is the new path to file that I am trying to work out. So after creating the dir and moving there. $0 only refers to when the file was launched - is it updatable?

Comment: @user969617: On which invocation would you like to know the new path? You cannot assign a value to `$0`, however since I began by copying its value into `$me` and using that thereafter it is possible to assign the new value to that variable, like `me="$path_to_me/$newdir/${me##*/}"`. Now `$me` is the full path to the script at its new location.

Comment: I understand that a script in this case a .command can find its path using `${0}` or directory `${0%/*}` but my script moves itself the first time it is run. let us say when we start the script that `dir=${0%/*}` when we move the script do we have to use `dir=${0%/*}/NewFolder` ? Obviously the second time the script is run, none of this is needed as `dir=${0%/*}` will work. Can `${0}` be flushed in any way? so it can be invoked after the script has moved and will find the new location? (without needing to amend it with `/NewFile`? Does this make sense? It's not a major problem just a curiosity

Comment: @user969617: No, this doesn't make sense. The first time you run the script `$0` is its original location. During the run of the script, the location of the script changes and `$0` doesn't change. During this first run you can use the variable `$me` to represent the new location after it moved, assigning to it if it moves as shown above. During the second run of the script the variable `$0` shows the new location. You can refer to this location as the variable `$me` during the second run of the script (and the location won't change again). You cannot under any circumstances alter $0 during run

Comment: ...and what's more, you don't need to.